# Is there a way to debug ExecuteMethodcall to retrieve the generated raw SQL call?

Tags: linq, debugging, stored-procedures, logging, dbml

We're currently using a stored procedure supplied by a third party, which we are accessing via a locally generated dbml file.

The third party has requested the SQL we are are generating for the call, but it is hidden inside the ExecuteMethodCall that is generated, e.g.:

```
IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo) .....
```

Because we don't have public access to the database we can't use MSSMS to monitor the calls to the database - so we need another method.

Is there a way to log the actual SQL generated inside the internal ExecuteMethodCall?